# Is there a way to automate a dist-upgrade at boot time?

Tags: upgrade, updates, bug-reporting, contributing

I run a bleeding-edge VM as bug reporting is about the only 'give back' activity that I have time to do.

I am however getting sick of things (understandably) crashing, only to be told 'Nope, we already fixed that yesterday, your packages are all old'.

**Has anyone come across an invisible way to update && upgrade on *boot*?** (i.e not login)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks so much for taking the time to find and report bugs in Ubuntu. It helps quite a bit. As you mention, during the development cycle things move very quickly and bugs are fixed on a daily basis. What we usually advise people to do is search for duplicates first; check if someone has already reported the bug you're observing before committing to filing a new one.

That said, you could create an upstart job to do apt-get update; apt-get -y dist-upgrade on boot (that is, if you don't mind upgrades potentially breaking your VM and/or leaving it in an unbootable state).

Here's a quick upstart primer:

http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are wanting to accomplish, but, IMO, this is not really a boot script, rather a question of how to automate updates.

I would configure automatic updates either in synatpic (graphical) or with unattended-upgrades (command line).

You may need to install synaptic

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Then configure automatic updates under the Updates tab

If you want it to automatically install these updates without notifying you,  check `Install security updates without confirmation` option. I believe this will install all updates from all repositories you have selected, and not just security only (it did last I looked).

[image: Synaptic]

To do this from the command line, install `unattended-upgrades`

```
sudo apt-get install unattended-upgrades
```

unattended-upgrades is intended for security updates on servers, but can be configured to your needs

Edit `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/50unattended-upgrades
```

And add in the repositories you want to use for your upgrades.

For details see [Ubuntu Server Guide Unattended Upgrades](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/automatic-updates.html)

When using your machine, if you find a bug, confirm you are up to date and search for duplicate bug reports as advised above.